# Generate terraform variables file from shell/bash script

Tags: bash, shell, terraform, jq, string-formatting

my requirement is to generate the terraform variables file based on the environment, I'm trying to generate them using bash/shell script, but having difficulty converting the output to terraform HCL language (I can't use JSON because I'm manipulating them further in terraform module)

Current API output (which needs to be converted into HCL):

```
'cluster_name1' 'REGION1' 'Volume_Size1' 'Instance_Size1'
'cluster_name2' 'REGION2' 'Volume_Size2' 'Instance_Size2'
'cluster_name3' 'REGION3' 'Volume_Size3' 'Instance_Size3'
{...}
```

Output in CSV format:

```
"cluster_name1","REGION1","Volume_Size1","Instance_Size1"
"cluster_name2","REGION2","Volume_Size2","Instance_Size2"
"cluster_name3","REGION3","Volume_Size3","Instance_Size3"
{...}
```

Required format:

```
variable "cluster_configuration" {
    default = [
    {   
        "cluster_name" : "cluster_name1"
        "cluster_region" : "REGION1"
        "instance_db_size" : "Volume_Size1"
        "instance_size" : "Instance_Size1"
    },
    {
        "cluster_name" : "cluster_name2"
        "cluster_region" : "REGION2"
        "instance_db_size" : "Volume_Size2"
        "instance_size" : "Instance_Size2"
    },
    {
        "cluster_name" : "cluster_name3"
        "cluster_region" : "REGION3"
        "instance_db_size" : "Volume_Size3"
        "instance_size" : "Instance_Size3"
    },
    {....}
    ]
}
```

My Terraform code, just for reference:

```
locals {
  dbconfig = [
    for db in var.cluster_configuration : [{
        instance_name = db.cluster_name
        db_size = db.instance_db_size
        instance_size = db.instance_size
        cluster_region = db.cluster_region
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have tried with AWK and SED but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Terraform can process suitably defined JSON objects. They are more verbose than the corresponding HCL, but easier to generate programmatically. See https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/syntax/json.

Comment: Could you show the bash code that you've tried?

Comment: @MarkReed I tried like this, `cat details| awk '{print "\"cluster_name\" : ", "\""$1"\"" "\"cluster_region\" : ", "\""$2"\"" }'`

Comment: @chepner, I've reviewed those documents already, but no luck so far.

Comment: You can also define a `TF_VAR_cluster_configuration` and assign that environment variable a value when running plan/apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform can process JSON data, if you define the objects correctly. You might be able to use `jq` to format the given CSV data into appropriate JSON for Terraform to consume. If I recall correctly, the filter would be something like

```
# This *very* much assumes that the quotes aren't actually
# quoting fields that contain a real comma. jq is not suitable
# for robustly parsing CSV data.
[
  inputs |
     split(",") |
     map(ltrimstr("\"")) |
     map(rtrimstr("\"")) |
     {
        cluster_name: .[0],
        cluster_region: .[1],
        instance_db_size: .[2],
        instance_size: .[3]
     }
] | {variable: {cluster_configuration: {default: .}}}
```

(There's probably room for improvement.) Assuming you save that to a file like `api.jq` and your API output is in `output.csv`, then

```
$ jq -nRf api.jq output.csv
{
  "variable": {
    "cluster_configuration": {
      "default": [
        {
          "cluster_name": "cluster_name1",
          "cluster_region": "REGION1",
          "instance_db_size": "Volume_Size1",
          "instance_size": "Instance_Size1"
        },
        {
          "cluster_name": "cluster_name2",
          "cluster_region": "REGION2",
          "instance_db_size": "Volume_Size2",
          "instance_size": "Instance_Size2"
        },
        {
          "cluster_name": "cluster_name3",
          "cluster_region": "REGION3",
          "instance_db_size": "Volume_Size3",
          "instance_size": "Instance_Size3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It might be simpler to pick the language of your choice with a proper CSV parser, though, to generate the JSON.

Comment: This solution is perfectly working, thanks for the help.. @chepner

Answer (score 1):

Solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

The content is as requested (but the specified formatting is disregarded)

```bash
INPUT="
'cluster_name1' 'REGION1' 'Volume_Size1' 'Instance_Size1'
'cluster_name2' 'REGION2' 'Volume_Size2' 'Instance_Size2'
'cluster_name3' 'REGION3' 'Volume_Size3' 'Instance_Size3'
"

jq -srR '
  split("\n") |        # split lines
  map(split(" ") |     # split fields
      select(any) |    # remove emty lines
      map(.[1:-1]) |   # remove enclosing quotes
      {
        cluster_name: .[0],
        cluster_region: .[1],
        instance_db_size: .[2],
        instance_size: .[3]
      }) |
  "variable \"cluster_configuration\" {",
  "    default = ",
  .,
  "}"
' <<< "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```
variable "cluster_configuration" {
    default = 
[
  {
    "cluster_name": "cluster_name1",
    "cluster_region": "REGION1",
    "instance_db_size": "Volume_Size1",
    "instance_size": "Instance_Size1"
  },
  {
    "cluster_name": "cluster_name2",
    "cluster_region": "REGION2",
    "instance_db_size": "Volume_Size2",
    "instance_size": "Instance_Size2"
  },
  {
    "cluster_name": "cluster_name3",
    "cluster_region": "REGION3",
    "instance_db_size": "Volume_Size3",
    "instance_size": "Instance_Size3"
  }
]
}
```